# Is the value of all methods loaded while making random choice from list in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am trying to come up with most efficient way of making random choice from bunch of methods that returns random value from the list inside those methods in Python.

```html
import random

def list1():
    list1 = ['apple', 'orange', 'banana']
    return random.choice(list1)

def list2():
    list2 = ['tomato', 'cauliflower', 'potato']
    return random.choice(list2)

def list3():
    list3 = ['milk', 'juice', 'water']
    return random.choice(list3)

def return_random():
    array_of_random = [list1(), list2(), list3()]
    return random.choice(array_of_random)

random_word = return_random()
print(random_word)

def return_random_modified():
    array_of_random2 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
    random_choice2 = random.choice(array_of_random2)
    if (random_choice2 == 'a'):
        return list1()
    if (random_choice2 == 'b'):
        return list2()
    if (random_choice2 == 'c'):
        return list3()

random_word2 = return_random_modified()
print(random_word2)
```

1. If I use method return_random() then will all the values returned by methods list1(), list2(), and list3() be loaded on array_of_random variable, or only value returned by method chosen by random.choice() is loaded on variable array_of_random?
2. If the answer of question 1 is yes, then is return_random_modified() the better way to do it, or is there another better way?
3. Eventually I am planning to use this strategy to make random API call to get random data, so I don't want to end up making call to all of external APIs and make random choice. I would rather prefer making call to only one random API.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `return_random` does execute `list1`, `list2`, and `list3` methods since you have `()` on them.

You fix that by moving the calling parentheses around to pass the function ***references*** to the `array_of_random` list and *then* calling that random function:

```
def return_random():
    array_of_random = [list1, list2, list3]
    return random.choice(array_of_random)()
```

Comment: Thank you for the answers to all my questions!

Answer (score 0):

You have `N` functions, and wish to avoid evaluating the `N - 1` functions that are not chosen. Good.

You wrote:

```
    array_of_random = [list1(), list2(), list3()]
    return random.choice(array_of_random)
```

The trouble, of course, is that 1st line does lots of work, most of which is for naught and will be discarded.

You want this instead:

```
    array_of_random = [list1, list2, list3]
```

The magic here is that we have `N` functions, but we don't evaluate them.

Then

```
    return random.choice(array_of_random)()
```

will call (evaluate) the single chosen function, ignoring the other `N - 1` functions.
Lazy, for the win!

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation!